# Si può usare la parola "rinominalo" in scrittura formale?

Tags: verbs, word-choice, vocabulary

Per curiosità ho cercato la parola "rinominalo" online e non ho trovato nessuna fonte ufficiale che ne certifica la correttezza.

Non [risulta apparire](https://www.dizy.com/it/voce/rinominare/verbo) nell'imperativo della sua coniugazione e [Google Ngram Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rinominalo%2Crinominato%2Crinominate%2Crinominiamo&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=33&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crinominato%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brinominato%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRinominato%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crinominate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brinominate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRinominate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crinominiamo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brinominiamo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRinominiamo%3B%2Cc0) risulta che la parola non è stata usata in nessuna pubblicazione ufficiale dal 1800 a oggi.

Sto guardando nei posti sbagliati, o "rinominalo" non è una parola **formalmente** accettata?

Answer (score 6):

Non so che cosa sia quel “Dizy” che citi, ma “rinominalo” non può esservi presente perché è una forma verbale (“rinomina”) a cui è aggiunto un pronome [enclitico](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/enclisi) (“-lo”). Quindi, nel complesso, “rinominalo” è una parola correttissima, come tutte quelle composte da una voce verbale e un pronome (“abbracciami”, “volerlo” etc.) o anche più di un pronome (“andarsene”, “dateglielo” etc.).

(Questo basterebbe, ma se può essere d'aiuto, per esempio in Google Books ci sono alcune occorrenze di “nominalo”, anche al netto degli errori di scansione per “nominale” e “nominato”.)

Comment: Grazie per la risposta. Mi era sembrato infatti strano, e Google Books mi ha messo dei grossi dubbi. Che tu sappia, ci sono dei falsi derivati nell'uso dei pronomi enclitici che vengono usati nel linguaggio comune? Quale risorsa online usi per controllare le coniugazioni dei verbi? Tra quelli che ho trovato io, Dizy mi è sempre sembrato il più affidabile.

Comment: Di questo Dizy non so niente, come dicevo, e quindi non so quanto possa essere affidabile: vedo che c'è dietro una società di consulenza informatica, non una casa editrice o un ente culturale... Personalmente uso il dizionario Zingarelli della Zanichelli, che per ogni verbo dà la coniugazione completa (ma è a pagamento); comunque anche il [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/) dà le eventuali voci irregolari o che possono creare dubbi. La questione sui falsi derivati è interessante: ci penso su, ma spero che intervenga anche qualcun altro.

Comment: Wiktionary ha una sezione con la coniugazione, per esempio [quella del verbo fare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fare#Conjugation). Le solite avvertenze sull'affidabilita' dei progetti Wikimedia, ma io mi sono sempre trovato bene.

Comment: @AlexF. occhio ad affidarsi solo agli Ngram. Le formazioni verbali in italiano (come in molte altre lingue con formazioni complesse di parole singole) possono comunque essere valide, indipendentemente dal loro utilizzo nello scritto: ciò non le rende meno corrette, ma solo meno comuni per tipicità della scrittura. Esattamente come un dizionario non riporta *tutte* le possibili coniugazioni di ogni verbo, o le formazioni di genere e dovute a pronomi, lo stesso accade per gli Ngram. Solo perché una parola non "esiste" nel dizionario, non significa che sia sbagliata.

Comment: @AlexF. Questo può portare a delle "stranezze", che però non sono di per sé degli errori. Parole composte come "salutiamoglielo" o "dileguandocisi", per quanto contorte ed estremamente rare, sono comunque grammaticalmente corrette eppure quasi introvabili, così come parole per così dire assurde tipo "piovendocene" o "salendosi". Che, poi, siano sintatticamente o concettualmente "sbagliate", è tutt'altro discorso.